# How to fix Warning Illegal string offset in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, casting, offset

I have this chunk of PHP code which is giving me the error:

> **Warning**:  Illegal string offset 'iso_format_recent_works' in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\Manta\wp-content\themes\manta\functions.php** on
>   line **1328**

This is the code that the warning is relating to:

```
if(1 == $manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']){
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_thumbnail';
} else {
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_iso_thumbnail';
}
```

When I do an a `var_dump($manta_option);` I receive the follow result:

> ["iso_format_recent_works"]=>   string(1) "1"

I have tried casting `$manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']` to an `int` but still get the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `var_dump()` showed that output, then your code should work as expected. Is the array getting modified in between? Show us the full code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Magic word is: **isset**

Validate the entry:

```
if(isset($manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']) && $manta_option['iso_format_recent_works'] == 1){
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_thumbnail';
} else {
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_iso_thumbnail';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks as though the array wasn't set properly.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This helped me a lot when i got the error on a WP site switching from php56 to php71!

Answer (score 3):

1.

```
 if(1 == @$manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']){
      $theme_img = 'recent_works_thumbnail';
 } else {
      $theme_img = 'recent_works_iso_thumbnail';
 }
```

2.

```
if(isset($manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']) && 1 == $manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']){
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_thumbnail';
} else {
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_iso_thumbnail';
}
```

3.

```
if (!empty($manta_option['iso_format_recent_works']) && $manta_option['iso_format_recent_works'] == 1){
}
else{
}
```

Comment: Code only answers do very little to educate the OP and future SO readers, please always include some sort of plain English explanation as to how your methods work and why they are appropriate solutions for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Please check that your key exists in the array or not, instead of simply trying to access it.

Replace:

```
$myVar = $someArray['someKey']
```

With something like:

```
if (isset($someArray['someKey'])) {
    $myVar = $someArray['someKey']
}
```

or something like:

```
if(is_array($someArray['someKey'])) {
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_iso_thumbnail';
}else {
    $theme_img = 'recent_works_iso_thumbnail';
}
```