# How to fix Warning: Illegal string offset 'code_class' when using foreach loop to print all data on array?

Tags: php

I am getting "Warning: Illegal string offset" on my project when I am try to use foreach loop to print data when search something from database

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'code_class' in F:\xampp\htdocs\manage_class1\Views\Home\home.php on line 33
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name_class' in F:\xampp\htdocs\manage_class1\Views\Home\home.php on line 34

My code:

home.php

```
foreach ($listClass as $row) {
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['code_class']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="index.php?controller=home&action=list&id=<?php echo $row['id_class'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name_class']; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

controller.php

```
case 'searchclass':
    $searchVal = $_POST['txtSearchClass'];
    $listClass = Home::Search('class', 'name_class', $searchVal);
    $listSub = Home::list('subjects');
    include('Views/Home/home.php');
break;
```

home_model.php

```
public static function Search($table, $column, $searchValue)
{
    $db = db::getInstance();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column LIKE '%{$searchValue}%'";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    $list = $query->fetch();
    return $list;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: do a `print_r($listClass);`. The issue should be there

Comment: What data is in `$listClass`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Warning Illegal string offset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279230/how-to-fix-warning-illegal-string-offset-in-php)

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale it return an array - Array ( [id_class] => 23 [0] => 23 [code_class] => 2222222222 [1] => 2222222222 [name_class] => Banhs [2] => Banhs )

Comment: @MrGlass it is an array with 3 object id_class, code_class and name_class!

Comment: @ThànhĐứcNguyễn, your problem is that `code_class` and `name_class` are arrays. You are trying to treat them as strings.

Comment: @MrGlass Thanks you! But how can I print my list data without using foreach loop?

Comment: You can use `implode(' ', $row['code_class'])`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php